# pagination for custom PHP site

Tags: php, pagination

I have custom PHP site and using this script for pagination.

```
echo "Page <strong>$pagenum</strong> of <strong>$last</strong><br><br>";
    if ($pagenum == 1)
    {
    }
    else
        {
        echo "<li> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'><strong>First page</strong></a></li>";
        echo " ";
        $previous = $pagenum-1;
        echo "<li> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'>".$previous."</a></li>";
        }

        echo "";


    if ($pagenum == $last)
        {           
        }
    else {
        $next = $pagenum+1;
        echo "  ....  <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'> ".$next."</a></li>";
        echo " ";
        echo "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'><strong>Last page</strong></a></li>";
    }
```

This only shows last two pages, not even first page. How to customize it to display first 5 and last 5 pages.

Comment: Wtf is a "custom" php site?

Comment: I don't know too much. Site is not in any open source CMS.

Comment: Apparently, the pages to display are in variable `$pagenum`. That is the variable to check.

Comment: It will show you a link to the 1st page if you're not on it. To show first 5 and last 5 needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: Learn about PHP, try something, come back with a concrete question. As it is now, it's a please write my code for me question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on where and how your pages are stored though! if you do that with a database, you would need to check if the $pagenum ( which we don't see defined anywhere ) has previous/next pages... and based on that you draw you +/- 5 pages anchors! preferably doing some looping!

On the other hand if you are not using any database and just want to show some content based on the ?pagenum=(number) which is what you seem to do here! you would need to get the current page via $_GET['pagenum'] once the user is on the new page! so that the content displays properly!

```
$pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? intval($_GET['pagenum']) : 0;
```

well then you simply do something like :

```
echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$first\">first</a>";

for ( $i = $pagenum-5; $i <= $pagenum+5; ++$i ) // check if the pages exist as well somewhere ;)
{
    if ( $pagenum != $i ) 
    {
        echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=".($i)."\">$i</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<a href=\"#\">Current</a>";
    }
}

echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last\">last</a>";
```

if that "method" is too basic to you have a look at this ones [simple-php-mysql-pagination](http://www.goodphptutorials.com/article/show/simple-php-mysql-pagination), [how-to-paginate-data-with-php](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/), [basic-pagination](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination)

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked alright :)